# How to check if a array input field starts with specific string in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an multiple input array fields like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="min[b][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="min[c][]" placeholder="Min" class="form-control">
```

Now i want to check whether iterating in a foreach loop the name of the field is min or not because it is array type so i cannot just compare its name. I have tried below code using regex but it is not working.

```
 $('.form-control').each(function() {
 var name = $(this).attr('name');
 var isMatch = /^min...$/.test(name);
 if(isMatch==true)
      {
```

Comment: If the goal is to get a jQuery object containing just the inputs starting with that name, you can use an attribute-starts-with selector:

    `const minInputs = $(".form-control[name^=min]");` or if you want to check for the opening `[` as well: `const minInputs = $(".form-control[name^='min[']");`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:I want to check in foreach loop whether current field start with min (and current field is array type)

Comment: @user3653474 You can use `.is('.form-control[name^=min]');` for that. https://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: @user3653474 - In that case, just `if (this.name.startsWith("min"))` within the loop does it, since jQuery sets `this` when calling the callback to the DOM element for that loop, and they have a `name` property which gives you a string, which has a `startsWith` method. (On older browsers: `if (this.name.substring(0, 3) === "min")` instead.)